# Controlling custom code usage in camunda modeller

Tags: camunda

I intend to use Camunda for my product. While all camunda abilities match with my needs, i have a concern about camunda modeler controlled usage. Following are my needs in modeller

- Is it possible to create custom domain specific tasks which i can simply drag-drop during modeling. It should be possible to define custom properties needed by this custom state
- Can I somehow control/prevent use of custom java code/scripts by person modeling process. I want to restrict use of only my custom tasks, so that we don't end up with lot of scattered code across processes.

Can experts share views to achieve these targets?

Answer (score 0):

Recently Camunda Modeler (I am using release 1.4.0, published on October 2016) has been extended to allow json template installation, which can meets all of your needs (if I understand them correctly), or at least the most of them. 
You may find documentation for templates build [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/modeler/camunda-modeler/element-templates/). The documentation is in progress, but what is already published I think it is quite clear. Briefly you have to

- list all the elements you want to customise (user tasks, general tasks, service tasks, listeners, links and so on)
- find out the json representation (explained in the short documentation) of each element
- insert all the jsoned elements in a file (for example: myElements.json)
- put the file in a specific modeler folder (see below)
- close and restart the modeler

For example if you have installed the modeler in `C:\Tools\camunda-modeler\`, the folder to publish the file into will be `C:\Tools\camunda-modeler\resources\element-templates` (note that *resources* will be already present, but *element-templates* will not; it will have to be created).

If all will be right the modeler will start without any error and you will find a new dropdown list selector on the right panel (as stated in  the documentation) for all the elements for which a template has been defined. Generally you have to classify each templates as either a user task, or a service task, or generic task and so on, so that when you want to use it you have to start from the generic element. For example, if you prepare in the json file 2 templates of kind of user task, say *userTask1* and *userTask2*, if you want to insert in your new process *userTask1* you have to

- pick up an empty userTask
- and choose from the *element template selector* on the right the voice *userTask1*, so that the empty user task becomes quickly the *userTask1* (with all my custom properties with my default values)
- that's it

To sum up, you may build templates with custom id and name (editable), with custom properties (editable or not, or even hidden), with eventual input/output parameters. So you may have default values properties and also tasks with simplified selections or without any selections at all.

You may find good starting examples to build your own templates [at this GIT repository](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-modeler/blob/master/resources/element-templates/samples.json).
Hope that is enough to understand.

Comment: This is probably the way to go, but note that the component is not yet in a [stable state](https://forum.camunda.org/t/state-of-the-modeler-element-template-feature/1511).